How to use non-relative path in typescript with esm?
I've been searching for hours now but still can't find a working solution.
I have a project in commonjs that works find with "non-relative" import paths :
src/app.ts:
import machin from 'test/test';

console.log('This is the app');
machin();

src/test/test.ts:
export default function machin() {
    console.log('This is the test !');
}

package.json:
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1+dev",
    "description": "",
    "main": "dist/app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "if [ \"${NODE_ENV}\" = production ]]; then npm run start:prod; else npm run start:dev;fi",
        "start:prod": "NODE_PATH=src/ node src/app.js",
        "start:dev": "npm run build &&  NODE_PATH=dist/src/ node dist/src/app.js",
        "build": "npm run clean && tsc && npm run copy-files",
        "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
        "copy-files": "cp ./package.json ./dist;cp ./tsconfig.json ./dist; cp ./version ./dist"
    },
    "author": {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "email": "jane.doe@acme.com"
    },
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^5.3.3"
    }
}

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/src",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    }
}

Now I want to use a esm module (geotiff js).
I want to migrate my commonjs to esm, but I can't wrap my head around how to keep my paths.
My last try is :
src/app.ts:
import machin from '@test/test';
...

package.json:
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
}


tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/src",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "paths": {
            "@test/*": ["src/test/*"]
        }
    }
}

In the dist/src/app.js produced, I have:
import machin from '@test/test';

And of course, this does not work.
It seems to be a hard to understand problem and I can't find anyone that have the exact same issue with a working solution.
Do you have an idea on how to this?
Thanks!

I finally found it, almost by chance!
During the compilation pipeline, in the build step of my package.json, I added tsc-alias. And that's (almost) all!
In my package.json:
{
    ...
    "main": "dist/app.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "build": "npm run clean && tsc && tsc-alias",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "tsc-alias": "^1.8.8"
    }
}

In my tsconfig.json:
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions":{
    ...
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist/src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}

Then, I changed all my imports by prepending a @/ and appending a .js, like in my src/app.ts
import machin from '@/test/test.js';

I found it very difficult to find this information, so I hope this topic will help others who face the same issue.
